# Enviar variable de una funcion a otro jsp

Tags: html, jsp

Tengo esta funcion que guarda una variable llamada alto..

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">
           var alto = document.getElementById('table').offsetHeight;
           //document.getElementById('parent.iframeCont'); obj.style.height = alto+"px";
      alert("Alt:" + alto);
</script>
```

Como puedo enviarla a otro JSP para utilizarla..